# How to tag fitness tracking questions?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I've just created [a question concerning the MSN Health & Fitness app](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/9258), but found myself in need of some tags that have something to do with fitness tracking, exercises, workouts, etc.

There's a [gps](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gps) tag, but I didn't think it was fitting because my question is not about location services (even though you create a new workout in the *Health & Fitness* app by clicking the <kbd>GPS Tracker</kbd> button.

What would be the best way of adding tags to this sort of question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the name of the app (so [health-fitness](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health-fitness) or [msn-health-fitness](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/msn-health-fitness)) is always an option, if no generic term can be found that's intuitive enough.

A few alternative suggestions:

- [activity-tracking](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/activity-tracking)

  "Activity tracker" seems to be a generic term for devices/apps that track health-related metrics.
- [fitness-tracking](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fitness-tracking)

  Specifically about fitness, if you want to distinguish from e.g. medical or nutritional tracking.
- [quantified-self](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantified-self)

  j/k ;)
- [sensor](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sensor)

  The piece of hardware that actually captures the data; might be a bit too technical, plus would include the unrelated proximity and ambient light sensors.
- [sensorcore](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sensorcore)

  The underlying technology; might again be too technical.